# How could i call a javascript function within the view of my ASP MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following JavaScript function in my view page :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function func(nam) {
    alert(nam);
</script>
```

My view code for calling this function goes like this on the same page:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  <script>func(@item.name) </script>
}
```

It does not produce any result.

I need to call the JavaScript function from within html but it is not happening. Kindly help me through it.

Is there any other way of calling the JavaScript function?

Comment: You don't have a closing bracket for your `func` function

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming your `item.Name` property has a string value `SomeThing`.So when razor render your page, your generated markup will be

```
<script> func(SomeThing) </script>
```

Now the javascript engine thinks that `SomeThing` is a js variable. But we do not have a js variable with that name defined and intialized earlier. So you might see a script error saying

> **SomeThing is not defined**

You need to pass the parameter as a string literal. Wrap it with single quotes or double quotes.

```
<script>func('@item.name') </script>
```

Also you need to make sure that `func` javascript method is defined before you try to execute the method.

```
<script>    
    function func(nam) {
        alert(nam);
    }
</script>

<script>func('@item.Name') </script>
```

If the function is inside an external js file, you need to make sure to include/load it before executing the method.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/YourJsFileWherFuncIsDefined.js"></script>
<script>func('@item.Name') </script>
```

Comment: thanks very much Shyju. It worked. A very very thanks. I was really stuck up.